# Plausible altitude for my planet's ring?

Tags: space, hard-science, atmosphere

The numbers come (relative to Earth and the Sun respectively unless indicated otherwise) as follows:

**Planet:**

- Mass: 1,32
- Radius: 1,24
- Gravity: 0,86
- Density: 0,69
- Semi-major axis: 1,24
- Escape velocity: 1,03
- Atmospheric pressure at surface level: 4,2 atm
- Scale height: 8342,9440799118 m
- Average atomic weight of the atmosphere: 0,02923690377 kg/mol

**Star:**

- Mass: 1,12
- Luminosity: 1,4868

**Ring:**

- Roche limit: 2,75 Earth radii
- Density: 0,92 of Earth's

I don't know if any other information would be needed (please do point it out if that's the case).

If Earth had rings, their upper boundary (altitude at which material would disperse or form micro satellites) would be the Roche limit given by it's density and Earth's and their lower boundary (altitude at which atmospheric drag would bring material down) approximately the end of the exosphere (around 10000km over Earth's surface).

**What would be a plausible lower boundary for my planet's rings with the given info?**

Comment: That's a very good point, thank you @StarfishPrime!

Comment: I think the height of the exosphere will depend on the planet's magnetic field strength. Venus has a thicker atmosphere but its exosphere starts much lower than Earth's, probably because of the lack of an intrinsic magnetic field.

Comment: Lmao you have your scale height measured down to one-ten-billionth of a meter...? (An ångström, on the scale of interatomic distances...?)

Comment: @BMF just excel things. I do like me some decimal precision ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Maybe you should start by providing units for your physical characteristics.